# How to define a GRPC service method without request parameter?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

Normally definde a GRPC method as follows which has a request parameter `HelloRequest`:

```java
// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

But how to define a method without request parameter as following `SayHello` method:

```java
// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello () returns (HelloReply) {}
}


// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google's [Well-Known Types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf) includes [`Empty`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Empty)

Given that you must have a message for requests and responses, I think it's a good idea to define them in your protos even if initially empty unless you're absolutely confident that they'll always be empty:

```protobuf
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

message HelloRequest {}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```